# How to implement Queue in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, message-queue, cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakePHP 1.3, i have used cron for screen the RSS from feeds but due to heavy loads some times my cron is break, after some research i have found queue is the replacement of Cron job.

i'm working with bellow code but i'm not able to do this. Can anyone help me how can i implement this?

```
 https://github.com/davidpersson/queue
```

My foldder structure is app/plugins/queue